# create an array that will hold all my info values for the current loop and insert some of those values into my link

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a table with an id and info column. and i want to run a loop in a wordpress page in order to display all my "info" values(name. phone, city...).using this snippet :

```
     global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wpeb_wpforms_entry_fields");
    foreach ( $result as $print )   { ?>
      <tr>
              <td>  <?php echo $print->id; ?> </td>
              <td><?php echo $print->entry_id; ?> </td>
              <td> <?php echo $print->form_id ; ?> </td>
              <td> <a href="url?Name=value1andCity=value2"><?php echo $print->info; ?> </a></td>
              <td><?php echo $print->mobile; ?> </td>
              <td> <?php echo $print->course; ?> </td>
              <td> <?php echo $print->address; ?> </td>
              <td><?php echo $print->city; ?> </td>
              <td> <?php echo $print->zip ; ?> </td>
      </tr>
        <?php }
  ?>
```

but I couldn't figure out how to create an array that will hold all my info values for the current loop and insert some of those values into my link/?value1=nameandvalue2=phone so I can submit those values to the target page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below PHP function to build query parameter:

```
$array = (array) $print;
http_build_query($array);
```

You can check more details here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php